# Cartesian/combination algorithm (while maintaining order)

Tags: algorithm, combinations, cartesian-product

Since I don't quite know the language of these types of algorithms (i.e. how to google this), I'll just demonstrate what I'm looking for:

I have a three arrays (source arrays are of not equal lengths):

```
$array1 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$array2 = array('x', 'y', 'z');
$array3 = array('1', '2', '3');
```

I would like all possible combinations of these arrays where:

- No more than one element from each source array is taken.
- The order of array1, array2, array3 is never broken (`ABC` always comes before `xyz` always comes before `123`).

So the result would be:

```
array(
  array('A', 'x', '1'),
  array('A', 'x', '2'),
  array('A', 'x', '3'),
  array('A', 'y', '1'),
  // etc ...

  // But I also need all the partial sets, as long as the rule about
  // ordering isn't broken i.e.:
  array('B'),
  array('B', 'x'),
  array('B', 'x', '1'),
  array('x'),
  array('x', '1'),
  array('1'),
);
```

The order of the results doesn't matter to me.

Working in php, but similar language or pseudo code is fine of course.  Or I'd just take a tip on what specific types of permutation/combination algorithms I should be looking at.

Comment: HINT: add a null ('') entry to each of your arrays, and change rule #1 to "*exactly* one element from each array".  ***Now*** its a cartesian product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say these are Cartesian products. Generating them is quite easy.

- for fixed number of arrays (in Perl):

  ```
  for my $a(@arrayA) {
    for my $b(@arrayB) {
      push @result, [$a, $b];
    }
  }
  ```
- general procedure: Assume `@partial` is an array for Cartesian product of `A1 x A2 x ... x An` and we want `A1 x ... x An x An+1`

  ```
  for my $a(@partial) {
    for my $b(@An_plus_1) {
      push @result, [@$a, $b];
    }
  }
  ```

  This would obviously need to iterate over all the arrays.

Now, that you want also to omit some of the elements in the sets, you just twist it a little. In the first method, you can just add another element to each of the arrays (`undef` is obvious choice, but anything will do) and then filter out these elements in the result sets. In the second method, it is even easier: You just add `@partial` and `map { [$_] } @An_plus_1` to the result (or, in English, all the sets resulting from the partial Cartesian product of `A1 x ... x An` plus the single element sets made form the elements of the new set).

Comment: Fantastic... yes, this is very simple with that extra undefined element.

Answer (score 0):

With RBarryYoung's hint, this is the shortest way to produce them, bash (and sed, to remove D, w, and 4):

```
echo {A..D}{w..z}{1..4} | sed 's/[Dw4]//g'
```

> A1 A2 A3 A Ax1 Ax2 Ax3 Ax Ay1 Ay2 Ay3 Ay Az1 Az2 Az3 Az
>   B1 B2 B3 B Bx1 Bx2 Bx3 Bx By1 By2 By3 By Bz1 Bz2 Bz3 Bz
>   C1 C2 C3 C Cx1 Cx2 Cx3 Cx Cy1 Cy2 Cy3 Cy Cz1 Cz2 Cz3 Cz 
>    1 2 3  x1 x2 x3 x y1 y2 y3 y z1 z2 z3 z

Another, easy way, is SQL, which does it by default:

```
SELECT upper, lower, num 
FROM uppers, lowers, numbers
WHERE upper in ('A', 'B', 'C', ' ')
AND lower in (' ', 'x', 'y', 'z')
AND (number in (1, 2, 3) OR number IS NULL);
```

If your tables only contain 'A,B,C, ,' and 'x,y,z, ,' and '1,2,3, ' it is much shorter:

```
SELECT upper, lower, num 
FROM uppers, lowers, numbers;
```

Another word, beside *cartesian product*, for this combinations is *cross product*.

For an unknown number of unknown size of Lists/Sequences/other collections, I would recommend an Iterator - if PHP has such things. Here is an implementation in Scala:

```
  class CartesianIterator (val ll: Seq[Seq[_]]) extends Iterator [Seq[_]] {
    var current = 0
    def size = ll.map (_.size).product
    lazy val last: Int = len

    def get (n: Int, lili: Seq[Seq[_]]): List[_] = lili.length match {
      case 0 => List () 
      case _ => {
        val inner = lili.head 
        inner (n % inner.size) :: get (n / inner.size, lili.tail) 
      }
    }

    override def hasNext () : Boolean = current != last
    override def next (): Seq[_] = {
      current += 1
      get (current - 1, ll) 
    }
  }

  val ci = new CartesianIterator (List(List ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ' '), List ('x', 'y', 'z', ' '), List (1, 2, 3, 0)))
  for (c <- ci) println (c)

List(A, x, 1)
List(B, x, 1)
List(C, x, 1)
List(D, x, 1)
List( , x, 1)
List(A, y, 1)
List(B, y, 1)
...
List( , z, 0)
List(A,  , 0)
List(B,  , 0)
List(C,  , 0)
List(D,  , 0)
List( ,  , 0)
```

A wrapper could be used to remove the '0' and ' ' from the output.